# Reading through XML in C#: null reference exception

Tags: c#, xml

**My code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Globalization;

namespace Read_Attribute
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String path = @"C:\\Users\\Sunny\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\taskl\\taskl\\bin\\Debug\\procy.xml";
            XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
            using (XmlTextReader tr = new XmlTextReader(path))
            {
                tr.Namespaces = false;
                xml.Load(tr);
            }
            XmlNodeList list = xml.GetElementsByTagName("omgdc:Bounds");
            XmlNodeList listt = xml.GetElementsByTagName("task");
            bool flag = true;
            bool flag1 = true;

            Double x1 = 0, x2 = 0, y1 = 0, y2 = 0;

            string c1 = null;
            string c2 = null;
            string v1 = null;
            string v2 = null;

            foreach (XmlNode m in listt)
            {
                if (m.Attributes.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (flag1)
                    {
                        c1 = (m.Attributes["id"].InnerText);
                        v1 = (m.Attributes["id"].InnerText);
                        flag1 = false;
                        Console.WriteLine("The id of task is: " + c1, "The id of task is: " + v1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        c2 = (m.Attributes["id"].InnerText);
                        v2 = (m.Attributes["id"].InnerText);
                        flag1 = true;

                        Console.WriteLine("The id of task is: " + c2, "The id of task is: " + v2);
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (XmlNode n in list)
            {
                String idStr = n.Attributes["id"].InnerText;
                if ((idStr != null) && ((idStr == c1) || (idStr == v1) || (idStr == c2) || (idStr == v2)))
                {
                    if (flag)
                    {
                        x1 = Convert.ToDouble(n.Attributes["x"].InnerText);
                        y1 = Convert.ToDouble(n.Attributes["y"].InnerText);
                        flag = false;
                        Console.WriteLine("The dimension of x is: " + x1);
                        Console.WriteLine("The dimension of y is: " + y1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        x2 = Convert.ToDouble(n.Attributes["x"].InnerText);
                        y2 = Convert.ToDouble(n.Attributes["y"].InnerText);
                        flag = true;

                        if (x2 > x1)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("The tasks don't overlap with each other");
                        }
                        else
                            Console.WriteLine("The tasks overlap with each other");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Regarding `String idStr = n.Attributes["id"].InnerText`: there was a null reference exception at this point. How can I remove this error?

I want to read XML through this code of a business process model. How can I remove the error as soon as possible?

Comment: Can you show your xml file?

Answer (score 1):

It’s difficult to identify the exact error without knowing what XML looks like. But there are a few corrections which may work for a null reference.

1. Is the path correct?

   ```
    String path = @"C:\\Users\\Sunny\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\taskl\\taskl\\bin\\Debug\\procy.xml";
   ```

   Any particular reason for extra escape character even when using `@`? I believe it should be like

   ```
    String path = @"C:\Users\Sunny\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\taskl\taskl\bin\Debug\procy.xml";
   ```

   Which means first check is, whether xml is actually getting loaded?
2. Add a check for Attributes:

   Something like

   ```
    if (n.Attributes["id"] != null)
   ```
3. Sure you need InnerText or is it value instead?

   Perhaps try this:

   ```
    String attributeValue = n.Attributes["id"].Value;
   ```